# Youtube embed code not loading until page refresh?

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed

Basically, I have a website that allows users to embed a Youtube video, Vimeo, Prezi, Scribd and a few other things.

Once they upload them, their embed code is saved to a database and the page is reloaded just like what happens when anything is sent to a SQL database through PHP. Although, the embedded movie/presentation will not show until the page is refreshed again.

Why is this happening? Must I somehow use a load priority make these embedded elements a priority to load straight away? This is my first time working with embed code, and I have searched online for solutions, although I could not find anything.

PS. Very new to PHP, MySQL and embedding.

Comment: @charmlessCoin - Sorry mate, would be slightly hard to do that without posting mountains and mountains of code that loads and posts the embed data to and from my database. Unless there is something specific you need?

Comment: Hmmm, I can't say I know much PHP either. This sounds like a hard thing to debug though, especially without code. Could be a bug in a lot of places.

Comment: I assume your users aren't actually uploading files ( for example via Youtube API) but they are adding embed codes, is that correct?

Comment: @LaurenZonneveld - That is correct. Only the embed code is saved into the database

Comment: @fizzix Did you ever find an answer to this? The same thing is happening to me, it's driving me crazy. Seems to be worse on chrome....

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox - Unfortunately, no. It is extremely annoying and I cannot seem to find a solution to this anywhere!